# How do I pass values into a UIView initializer from a XIB?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, xib

I have made a custom UIView XIB file with some outlets. I want to be able to load it programmatically from other places in my code. I am using autolayout in the xib. My problem is that I need to initialize it with a parameter value to satisfy a delegate method. I am not sure how to pass the parameter during initialization. I also don't really understand the whole init(frame:) vs init(coder:) and how a convenience init would work here. Any advice?

Background: currently the entire view is programmatic in Obj-C and I am porting it to XIB with swift.

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot of different way to handle the initialization of a view. you could create a static function that does all the work for you. that's one way to avoid the override of the init methods.

```
class TestView: UIView {
    var delegate: Any!

    static func instantiate(with delegate: Any) -> TestView {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "TestView", bundle: nil)
        guard let testView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil)[0] as? TestView else {
            fatalError("Attempted to create TestView, failed to find object")
        }
        testView.delegate = delegate
        return testView
    }
}
```

Then you do the following to create your view

```
let testView = TestView.instantiate(with:mydelegate)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution. Worked for me!

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class NotFoundView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var lblContentTitle: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        customize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        customize()
    }

    private func customize() {
        print("customize")

        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NotFoundView", owner: self, options: nil)
               addSubview(contentView)
               contentView.frame = self.bounds
               contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }
}
```

---

```
let notFoundView = NotFoundView()
notFoundView.lblContentTitle.text = "Not found. Please try again..."

return notFoundView
```